# Почему не решается пример из массива?

Tags: javascript

```js
var a= "6 + 9 = 16";
console.log(a.split('=')[0]) //проблема
console.log(6 + 9) //то что надо
```

Comment: А с чего бы ему решаться?

Comment: наверное потому, что девять плюс шесть не равно шестнадцати

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тут подойдет [eval()](https://learn.javascript.ru/eval)

```js
var a= "6 + 9 = 16";
console.log(eval(a.split('=')[0]))
console.log(6 + 9) //то что надо
```

Answer (score 2):

Не решается, потому что в `a.split('=')[0] = "6 + 9"` тип данных - это string (строка), а математические операции выполняются с типом данных number (число), в котором кавычки не используются.

Разница:

`console.log(6 + 9)`

`console.log("6 + 9")`

С кавычками решаться не будет. Чтобы решалось с кавычками, нужно использовать `eval()` вот так:

console.log(eval("6 + 9"))

console.log(eval(a.split('=')[0]))